# Detect click in Compose TextField

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-compose-textfield

I am trying to implement an onClick handler for a Compose TextField.  Current functionality is to handle the TextField click but disable manually editing of the field.  For my use case I would like to handle the click and do something else.  I would like to keep the look and feel of a TextField, and would like the focus animation to also happen.

the readOnly property gives me what I want from a UX perspective, however when I click on the TextField the onClick handler is not called.

```
TextField(
  value = text,
  onValueChange = { text = it},
  readOnly = true,
  modifier = Modifier
    .clickable(onClick = {
      Log.i("TextField", "Clicked")
    })
)
```

I have also tried to use pointerInput, how I am having the same problem.

```
TextField(
  value = text,
  onValueChange = { text = it},
  readOnly = true,
  modifier = Modifier
    .pointerInput(Unit) {
      detectTapGestures(onTap = {
        Log.i("TextField", "Clicked")
      }
    }
)
```

With Compose being so new its hard to tell if this is a bug or intended.

Answer (score 19):

Using `readOnly = true` the `TextField` is still enabled and the first click gives the focus to the field. You have to perform a double click to handle your `onClick` function.

Otherwise you can use the `enabled` property:

```
   TextField(
        enabled = false,
        modifier = Modifier.clickable(onClick = {/* ... */})
    )
```

Something like:

```
TextField(
    value = text,
    onValueChange = { text = it},
    enabled = false,
    modifier = Modifier
        .clickable { text= "Clicked"},
    colors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(
        disabledTextColor = LocalContentColor.current.copy(LocalContentAlpha.current),
        disabledLabelColor =  MaterialTheme.colors.onSurface.copy(ContentAlpha.medium)
    )
)
```

[image]

Comment: So sounds like I just need to figure out a way to revert the Text and Label colors to non-disabled.

Comment: @lostintranslation Yes. I've updated the answer with an example reverting the `disabledTextColor` and the `disabledLabelColor` to the default non-disabled colors.

Comment: Thank you.  Out of curiosity, is there a way to attach my own click handler that works when using readOnly?  I was trying to go down that route without much success.

Comment: @lostintranslation Sorry but I am able to work with your code only doing a double click in the field.

Answer (score 18):

Maybe the better way to detect click events in text field is using interaction source.

step 1 : - **Create an interaction source**

```
 val source = remember {
    MutableInteractionSource()
}
```

**step 2: - pass it to text field**

```
 OutlinedTextField(
    value = text,
    readOnly = true,
    onValueChange = {},
    textStyle = MaterialTheme.typography.body1.copy(
        lineHeight = if (isFocused) 25.sp else TextUnit.Unspecified,
        fontWeight = if (isFocused) FontWeight.SemiBold else FontWeight.Normal
    ),
    label = {
        Text(
            text = label,
            fontWeight = if (isFocused) FontWeight.SemiBold else FontWeight.Normal,
            style = MaterialTheme.typography.caption
        )
    },
    interactionSource = source,
    colors = TextFieldDefaults.outlinedTextFieldColors(
        textColor = if (isFocused) MaterialTheme.colors.primary else LocalContentColor.current
    ),
    maxLines = if (isFocused) Int.MAX_VALUE else 2,
    modifier = Modifier
        .padding(
            start = COUNTER_WIDTH + 16.dp,
            top = padding,
            bottom = padding,
            end = 16.dp
        )
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .verticalScroll(enabled = isFocused, state = rememberScrollState())
        .animateContentSize(animationSpec = tween(DURATION))
)
```

**step: 3- collect pressed flow as state and observe changes to it.**

```
 if ( source.collectIsPressedAsState().value)
        onClicked()
```

Comment: IMHO, this seems to be the most accurate answer, without any side-effects or workarounds.

Comment: @rewgoes I think there is a side effect  https://stackoverflow.com/a/73740797/9107280

Comment: @rewgoes see https://stackoverflow.com/a/73740797/14056648

Comment: this isn't good, it fires as soon as you tap on the field and don't event remove your finger

Answer (score 15):

The correct asnwer would be to use `interactions` of `InteractionSource` and not `collectIsPressedAsState`! The last one just checks when you tap on something but it ignores the fact that you don't even release your finger

```
TextField(
    value = ...,
    onValueChange = { ... },
    interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() }
        .also { interactionSource ->
            LaunchedEffect(interactionSource) {
                interactionSource.interactions.collect {
                    if (it is PressInteraction.Release) {
                        // works like onClick
                    }
                }
            }
        }
)
```

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/70335041/7767664

Answer (score 9):

To me, it seems the top answer has one major problem.

```
if ( source.collectIsPressedAsState().value)
    onClicked()
```

`onClicked()` will trigger even if press is `canceled` because you are not waiting to see the end state after the press.
When you are scrolling, if your touch is in the same position as the textField, onClick will get triggered and I'm sure that's unwanted interaction 99% of the time.

```
val pressedState=source.interactions.collectAsState(
      initial = PressInteraction.Cancel(PressInteraction.Press(Offset.Zero)))
       
    if (pressedState.value is PressInteraction.Release)
    {
        dropDownExpanded.value = true
        onClick?.invoke()
        source.tryEmit(PressInteraction.Cancel(PressInteraction.Press(Offset.Zero)))
    }
```

if you do something like this it eliminates the unwanted onClick while scrolling

Comment: What does the `dropDownExpanded.value = true` do? I don't see it anywhere else

Comment: @radda it is a state to show the dropdown menu if you have one, in my case, there is one and I pass it to the composable that wraps the whole TextField and the DropDownMenu

Answer (score 4):

If you want to keep `readOnly=true` for UX reasons, `clickable` modifier won't work but this one will  :

```
TextField(
    readOnly = true,
    modifier = Modifier.pointerInput(Unit) {
        awaitEachGesture {
            awaitFirstDown(pass = PointerEventPass.Initial)
            val upEvent = waitForUpOrCancellation(pass = PointerEventPass.Initial)
            if (upEvent != null) {
                // YOUR CALLBACK
            }
        }
    }
)
```

Answer (score 2):

For someone who seeks for a simple onclick function without the need of focus animation, I figured out a way that @lostintranslation may have tried. The trick is clearing focus in `onFocusChanged`. This way keeps the `TextField` enabled-style but leaves two problems:

1. no focus animation (other animations work well)
2. when the user wants to long press to copy the text, it calls the onclick first.

```java
val focusManager = LocalFocusManager.current

TextField(
        value = ...,
        label = ...,
        readOnly = true,
        modifier = Modifier.onFocusChanged {
                if (it.isFocused) {
                    yourOnClick()
                    // clear focus here
                    focusManager.clearFocus()
          }
    )
```