# Jetpack Compose: TextField clickable does not work

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-compose-textfield

for some reason Compose TextField's click listener does not work for me.

```
@Composable
    private fun ExposedDropdown(
        modifier: Modifier,
        list: List<String>,
        priority: Int
    ) {
        var expanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
        Column(modifier) {
            OutlinedTextField(
                value = list[priority],
                onValueChange = { },
                readOnly = true,
                singleLine = true,
                label = { Text(stringResource(id = R.string.status)) },
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .clickable { Timber.i("Not working :(") }
                    .onFocusChanged { if (it.isFocused) expanded = !expanded },
                trailingIcon = {
                    Icon(
                        imageVector = Icons.Outlined.ArrowDropDown,
                        contentDescription = null,
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .clickable { expanded = !expanded }
                            .padding(16.dp)
                    )
                }
            )
            DropdownMenu(
                expanded = expanded,
                onDismissRequest = { expanded = false }
            ) {
                list.forEach { label ->
                    DropdownMenuItem(onClick = {
                        viewModel.setPriority(list.indexOf(label))
                        expanded = false
                    }) {
                        Text(text = label)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

As you can see I come up with bad solution using `onFocusChanged` but it does not work well.

For those who need context, I'm trying to do ExposedDropdown but I want it to open when I click anywhere on TextField

Answer (score 39):

Another possible workaround can be this:

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.collect

TextField(
    value = ...,
    onValueChange = { ... },
    interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() }
        .also { interactionSource ->
            LaunchedEffect(interactionSource) {
                interactionSource.interactions.collect {
                    if (it is PressInteraction.Release) {
                        // works like onClick
                    }
                }
            }
        }
)
```

Comment: so others dont stumble on this, make sure you use `import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.collect ` as the sourse of collect else you will get a weird exception. apparently someone at kotlin decided to have a second method named collect in the same library XD

Comment: finally somebody gave the correct answer with check `if (it is PressInteraction.Release) {`, there are many answers where it's just `val isPressed: Boolean by interactionSource.collectIsPressedAsState()` which fires as soon as you tap and don't event release your finger

Comment: worth to note:
does not force to set `enabled = false` to receive callback.

Comment: How to add ripple effect?

Comment: This is neat because it's not a workaround like the other answers: you don't have to set other fields out of their original meaning (like enabled = false) and according to https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/172154008 as "swallowing the click event" is intended by default, this simply overrides it.

Comment: use ```if (it is PressInteraction.Release || it is PressInteraction.Cancel) {``` for desktop target

Answer (score 26):

with compose **1.0.2** it works by default. Need to add line `enabled = false`

Example

```
@Composable
fun SelectableTextField(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    textValue: String,
    onClick: () -> Unit
) {
    TextField(
        value = textValue,
        onValueChange = {},
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .clickable { onClick() },
        enabled = false
    )
}
```

to remove ripple effect, use such extension

```
inline fun Modifier.noRippleClickable(crossinline onClick: () -> Unit): Modifier =
    this.then(
        composed {
            clickable(indication = null,
                interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() }) {
                onClick()
            }
        })
```

Comment: Why do we have to have `enabled = false` to have `clickable` work?

Comment: Found this bug that outlines the reason https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/172154008 - Please star/comment if you think this should work differently

Answer (score 16):

The suggestion of setting the enabled attribute as false works, but this affects the style.
If you want it to visually match an enabled TextField then set the colors attribute accordingly:

```
OutlinedTextField(
   value = "Example",
   enabled = false,
   onValueChange = {},
   modifier = Modifier.clickable { doSomeBehavior() },
   colors = TextFieldDefaults.outlinedTextFieldColors(
      disabledTextColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onSurface,
      disabledBorderColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.outline,
      disabledPlaceholderColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onSurfaceVariant,
      disabledLabelColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onSurfaceVariant,
      //For Icons
      disabledLeadingIconColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onSurfaceVariant,
      disabledTrailingIconColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onSurfaceVariant)
)
```

Comment: like the idea, but unfortunately it does not get focused (focus remains at previously selected text field). How to fix that?

Answer (score 10):

```
val interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() }
val isPressed: Boolean by interactionSource.collectIsPressedAsState()

LaunchedEffect(isPressed){
    if (isPressed) {
        // Click action
    }
}

TextField(
value = textFieldValue,
onValueChange = onTextFieldChange,
interactionSource = interactionSource
)
```

Comment: how to test this? The functionality is there but `performClick` won't trigger the click callback :/

Comment: This could run the isPressed handler any number of times. It should use LaunchedEffect e.g. `LaunchedEffect(isPressed) { if(isPressed) { /* Click Action */ }}`

Comment: this is not really correct, it fires as soon as you tap on the field and don't event remove your finger, it should be called only after you release the finger, you can't even scroll normally in the column when you have many text fields with it

Answer (score 8):

The `clickable` modifier currently (`1.0.0-beta08`) doesn't work with a `TextField`.

It is a workaround, not a real solution.
Since your `TextField` is readonly, you can wrap the `OutlinedTextField` with in a `Box` using a second `Box` to handle the click.

```
 val focusRequester = FocusRequester.createRefs()
 val interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() }

 Box() {
        OutlinedTextField(
          //...your code
          modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .focusRequester(focusRequester)
        }
                    
        if (!expanded) {
            Box(modifier = Modifier
                .matchParentSize()
                .clickable(
                    onClick = {
                        expanded = !expanded
                        focusRequester.requestFocus() //to give the focus to the TextField
                              },
                    interactionSource = interactionSource,
                    indication = null //to avoid the ripple on the Box
                ))
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, but using this solution I won't be able to copy or interact with TextField's content right?

Comment: @androboy No, but in your code it is `enable` but `readOnly = true`. Do you want also to support the select/copy?

Comment: Not really required but would be better.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a possible solution. I've created a `collectClickAsState()` composable based on `androidx.compose.foundation.interaction.collectIsPressedAsState`:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun CustomTextField(
    value: String,
    onValueChange: (String) -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    enabled: Boolean = true,
    onClick: (() -> Unit)? = null,
) {
    val onClickSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() }

    if (onClick != null) {
        if (onClickSource.collectClickAsState().value) {
            onClick.invoke()
        }
    }

    TextField(
        value = value,
        onValueChange = onValueChange,
        interactionSource = onClickSource,
        enabled = enabled,
        readOnly = onClick != null,
        modifier = modifier
            // add clickable to work with talkback/accessibility
            .clickable(enabled = enabled) { onClick?.invoke() },
    )
}

@Composable
fun InteractionSource.collectClickAsState(): State<Boolean> {
    val onClick = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    LaunchedEffect(this) {
        var wasPressed = false
        interactions.collect { interaction ->
            when (interaction) {
                is PressInteraction.Press -> {
                    wasPressed = true
                }
                is PressInteraction.Release -> {
                    if (wasPressed) onClick.value = true
                    wasPressed = false
                }
                is PressInteraction.Cancel -> {
                    wasPressed = false
                }
            }
            // reset state with some delay otherwise it can re-emit the previous state
            delay(10L)
            onClick.value = false
        }
    }
    return onClick
}
```

With this solution, the text field is still focusable, the text is selectable and it will use the correct UI enabled state.

Answer (score 1):

```
TextField(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .**clickable**(onClick = onClick),
        enabled = false,
        value = currentSelection,
        onValueChange = { },
        label = {
            
        }
    )
```

use the enabled = false and clickable modifier.