# TextField onValueChange is Called When Focused

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

Using TextField in Compose, I found that looks like a bug.
When I change the textfield value , focus out and in again,
onValuseChange method is called even there is no change.
this is not What I want, So I write some defending code for this comparing prev value.
But I want to know another nice solution.
here is my code.

```
onValueChange = { _inputText ->
               
                if(_inputText.text != countState.value){
                   
                }
            },
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `onValueChange: (TextFieldValue) -> Unit` callback, it will be called when you focus or unfocus `TextField`. This is because focus puts cursor into TextField and it's state is saved into `TextFieldValue`.

Comment: but only if text is not empty

Answer (score 0):

Use `interactionSource` parameter that keeps track of the interaction track of the `TextField` and you can apply it to detect when the Text changes due to user interaction.

- [Reference0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67902919/jetpack-compose-textfield-clickable-does-not-work)
- [Reference1](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/interaction/InteractionSource)
- [Reference2](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/touch-input/handling-interactions)