# How to get string annotation onClick from TextField jetpack compose (android)?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-compose-textfield

When using compose,  I've got a `TextField` that is created with an `AnnotatedString` which contains string annotations with a particular tag.

I've found a few answers on how to handle clicks inside the TextField, like so:

```kotlin
TextField(
    value = ...,
    onValueChange = { ... },
    interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() }
        .also { interactionSource ->
            LaunchedEffect(interactionSource) {
                interactionSource.interactions.collect {
                    if (it is PressInteraction.Release) {
                        // works like onClick
                    }
                }
            }
        }
)
```

(source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70335041/)

However, this just gives me if the TextField has been clicked, not *what* in the `TextField` was clicked, so there's no way to find the if the text that was clicked on was annotated or not.  In a `ClickableText` I could find this like so:

```kotlin
ClickableText(
    text = text,
    onClick = { offset ->
        text.getStringAnnotations(offset, offset).firstOrNull()?.let {
            if (it.tag == "MY_TAG") {
                // handle click on my tag
            }
        }
    },
```

I can't seem to find a way to do similarly with a TextField.  Is there any way to achieve this?