# OutlinedTextField in jetpack compose on click open Time picker and update the OutlinedTextField

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack

android OutlinedTextField on click and open to time picker
its only work in label text click how to click whole OutlinedTextField on event

```
OutlinedTextField(
                            value = selectedTimeState,
                            onValueChange = { selectedTimeState = it },
                            label = { Text("Selected Time") },
                            modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxWidth().clickable {
                                Toast.makeText(context, "click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                            },
                            readOnly = true,
                            trailingIcon = {
                                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(8.dp))
                                Text(
                                    text = AnnotatedString(text = lateTimeState),
                                    style = MaterialTheme.typography.bodySmall
                                )
                                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(8.dp))
                            },
                        )
```

[image]

android OutlinedTextField on click and open to time picker

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jetpack Compose: TextField clickable does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67902919/jetpack-compose-textfield-clickable-does-not-work)

Comment: Do you want to open timer dialog when any part of the outlineTextfield clicked?

Answer (score 0):

```
val datePicker = DatePickerDialog(
        context, { _: DatePicker, selectedYear: Int, selectedMonth: Int, selectedDayOfMonth: Int ->
   
            calendar[Calendar.YEAR] = selectedYear
            calendar[Calendar.MONTH] = selectedMonth
            calendar[Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH] = selectedDayOfMonth
            if (isDOB) {
                selectedDateText = formatterDate(
                    Date(calendar.timeInMillis).toString(),
                    "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy",
                    "yyyy-MM-dd"
                )!!
                onValueChange(selectedDateText)
            } else {
                val convertingInUTCFromCalendar = formatterDate(
                    Date(calendar.timeInMillis).toString(),
                    "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy",
                    "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS"
                )!!
                val parsed: DateTime =
                    DateTime(convertingInUTCFromCalendar).withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC)

                val myUTCFormat = formatterDate(
                    parsed.toString(),
                    "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS",
                    "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
                )

                selectedDateText = myUTCFormat!!
                onValueChange(selectedDateText)
            }
        }, calendar[Calendar.YEAR], calendar[Calendar.MONTH], calendar[Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH]
    )


    OutlinedTextField(
        value = selectedDateText,
        onValueChange = { onValueChange(it) },
        readOnly = true,
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .wrapContentHeight(),
        keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
            capitalization = KeyboardCapitalization.Characters,
            autoCorrect = false,
        ),
        placeholder = {
            Text(
                text = "dd/mm/yyyy",
                fontWeight = FontWeight(400),
                fontSize = 14.sp,
                color = RomanSilver,
            )
        },
        trailingIcon = {
            IconButton(
                onClick = { datePicker.show() },
            ) {
                Icon(
                    painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.calendar),
                    contentDescription = null,
                    tint = RomanSilver
                )
            }
        },
        colors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(
            backgroundColor = MaterialTheme.colors.secondaryVariant,
            cursorColor = RomanSilver,
            disabledLabelColor = RomanSilver,
            focusedIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent,
            unfocusedIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent,
            textColor = LocalCustomColorsPalette.current.textColor,
            disabledTextColor = LocalCustomColorsPalette.current.textColor,
            disabledIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent
        ),
        shape = (RoundedCornerShape(40)),
        isError = isError,
        keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(onDone = { focusManager.clearFocus() }),
        interactionSource = interactionSource
    )
```

using the above code I have achieved the same thing and this is just for your reference because I have created my own composable function for my requirements If you don't understand many think's feel free to ask in comment.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to use the solution given above and partially achieved the result. I am getting calendar option when I click icon but the selected date is not appearing in the `OutlinedText` field.

**Dependencies:**

```
// CORE
implementation("com.maxkeppeler.sheets-compose-dialogs:core:1.0.2")

// CALENDAR
implementation("com.maxkeppeler.sheets-compose-dialogs:calendar:1.0.2")
```

```kotlin
var dateOfBirth by mutableStateOf("")
val calendarState = rememberSheetState()

OutlinedTextField(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
    value = dateOfBirth,
    singleLine = true,
    onValueChange = { dateOfBirth = it },
    readOnly = true,
    placeholder = {
        Text(
            text = "dd/mm/yyyy",
            fontWeight = FontWeight(400),
            fontSize = 14.sp,
        )
    },
    trailingIcon = {
        IconButton(onClick = { calendarState.show() }) {
            Icon(
                painter = painterResource(R.drawable.dateicon),
                contentDescription = null,
                Modifier.size(32.dp)
            )
        }
    },
    label = {
        Text(
            text = stringResource(R.string.enter_DoB)
        )
    },
)
```

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35702061)